# How to check ar's return value in shell script?

Tags: shell

I am using 'ar' to build an archive file within a shell script. How do I check if it succeeded or failed?

Comment: A quick search would yield many, many results, like [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/shell-how-to-determine-the-exit-status-of-linux-and-unix-command/) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man ar`:

> The ar utility exits 0 on success, and >0 if an error occurs.

In other words: it exhibits standard behavior.

Various ways of checking (`ar ...` represent the specific `ar` command):

```
ar ... || { echo "Failure" 1>&2; exit 1; }

# ---

if ! ar ...; then # act on failure

# ---

# Note: $? is a special variable containing the *most recently executed* 
#       command's exit code.
ar ... ; ar_status=$?  
if (( ar_status != 0 )); then # act on failure
```

Comment: Clear answer, but I would suggest that you explicitly mention that $? is the shell variable which holds the results of the last command, for every command.

Comment: @ChuckCottrill Agreed that it's worth mention, but `$?` is severely overused; best practice is to branch on success/failure without explicitly storing or inspecting it where possible.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm new to shell scripting and your answer really helps, not only in the way of problem solving:)

Comment: @Diaz: You're welcome. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is a good guide to bash scripting. `man bash` itself contains a lot of information, too, though pretty condensed and daunting to beginners. In addition to `man`pages, many utilities also support `--help` and/or `-h` to show at least the syntax. For bash builtins such as `read`, use `help read`.

Answer (score 0):

`$?` is used for return code of last command executed.

You don't need anything specific for `ar` to capture that information.